# Старые проекты (из 2010 в 2013)

Tags: visual-studio

Раньше никогда не сталкивался с переносом проектов со старой версии VS2010 в новую VS2013

В итоге у меня проект выдает стандартную ошибку:

> Ошибка    1   error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" завершилась с кодом 3.

Я знаю, что надо где-то прописать просто пути, но не знаю где именно.

Comment: И это единственное что студия при сборке выдает?

Comment: А как вы делаете перенос? Просто открывая проект созданный в старой версии через новую? или как то еще?

Comment: да просто открывая, студия вроде поддерживает автоматическое обновление проекта